# Use of undefined constant App - assumed 'App' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create application with laravel 4. I created Answer Model with the following code.

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class Answer extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();
}
```

and I already seeded with sample data. But while I tried with command line in the following;

```
php artisan tink
echo App\Models\Answer::all();
```

It showed

```
Use of undefined constant App - assumed 'App'
```

Instead of sample data with JSON format. Please find me a solution for this.

Comment: Is this working if you request it via Web? Are your namespaces being correctly resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your namespace your `Answer` model should be in `app/models/app/models` and to extend the class you should use

```
class Answer extends \Eloquent
```

instead of

```
class Answer extends Eloquent
```

But, I think you can get rid of this `namespace`, if your `Answer` model is inside `app/models` folder of you application's root folder then you don't need to use this `namespace`. By default `"app/models"` is provided in to `autoload` section of the `composer.json` file and `Laravel` will load models from this location and if you want to use any namespace in your model then create directories according to namespace and put your model in that directory under `app/model`, so, if your namespace for a model is `Project/entity` then, your model should be in `app/models/project/entity` folder and when you use your `model` you may use it like

```
project\entity\YourModel
```